# Skydrive integration in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, onedrive

I'm developing an app where I have integrated sky drive framework.But when I try to login my app crashes.

Here is my code

```
(IBAction)signInMethod:(id)sender { self.liveClient =
[[LiveConnectClient alloc] initWithClientId:APP_CLIENT_ID 
                                                     delegate:self 
                                                    userState:@"initialize"]; }

- (void)authCompleted:(LiveConnectSessionStatus) status 
          session:(LiveConnectSession *) session 
        userState:(id) userState { if ([userState isEqual:@"initialize"]) {
    NSLog(@"initialized");
    [self.liveClient login:self 
                    scopes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"wl.signin", nil] 
                  delegate:self 
                 userState:@"signin"];

} if ([userState isEqual:@"signin"]) {
    if (session != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"signed in");      
    }
     } }

- (void)authFailed:(NSError *) error 
     userState:(id)userState { NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]]); //   
[self.infoLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@",
[error localizedDescription]]]; }
```

**Edit**

Now I'm able to login. I was getting error because I didn't integrated the framework properly.

Comment: Any details at all about the crash itself? You can hopefully provide the symbolicated crash report. Without this, we would have to do wild guesses which hopefully is not intended.

Comment: is there any error log there?